# When observing a notification that may be posted "on a thread other than the one used to registered the observer," how to ensure thread-safe UI work?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, foundation

I observe when an `AVPlayer` finishes play in order to present a `UIAlert` at the end time.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(presentAlert),
  name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
  object: nil
)
```

I've had multiple user reports of the alert happening where they're not intended, such as the middle of the video after replaying, and on other views. I'm unable to reproduce this myself, but my guess is that it's a threading issue since [AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime) says "the system may post this notification on a thread other than the one used to registered the observer."

How then do I make sure the alert is present on the main thread? Should I dispatch to the main queue from within my `presentAlert` function, or add the above observer with `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` instead, passing in the main operation queue?

Comment: both options are valid, why don't you try them?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I'm unable to determine a difference in reliability between both if I can't reproduce the problem to begin with (the notification being posted to a background queue). Looking to see if there are considerations when choosing an approach that I'm missing.

Comment: I would say that both are equally reliable, I don't think there is any significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Alert and any other UI Operation should always be performed on main thread. You can verify if thread is main or not by using Thread.isMainThread.

If it's on main thread already then delay is not due to this. Getting delay on AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime could be due to use of serial queue. Will need some code snippet to be sure.